# Background Image is not showing in a [ngStyle] Angular 2

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm having trouble trying to show a image in a div and I kinda don't understand why, could someone help me with this? I know that the methods work cause i used them in different places but i'm not sure if the format of the div is correct.

```
<div class="attachment-element" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + isPdf(imgUri) ? 'assets/img/pdf_preview.png' : imgUri + ')'}">
```

Answer (score 1):

use only **background** attribute of style as given below

```
<div class="attachment-element" [ngStyle]="{'background': 'url(' + isPdf(imgUri) ? 'assets/img/pdf_preview.png' : imgUri + ')'}">
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), your image URL expression is equivalent to the following:

```
('url(' + isPdf(imgUri)) ? 'assets/img/pdf_preview.png' : (imgUri + ')')
```

which results in an incorrect format. See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bicb1s) for a demo.

---

You should put parentheses around the conditional operator to get the appropriate format:

```
'url(' + (isPdf(imgUri) ? 'assets/img/pdf_preview.png' : imgUri) + ')'
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1uvzub) for a demo.